# Macro corrupts my Excel file if executed when open file

Tags: excel, vba, file, corrupt

I made a macro that when executed, create 2 arrays of strings with all the files in specific folders, then creates a drop down data validation in a cell, if i manually execute the macro everything works perfect, if i save the file and reopen it, well, all works perfect, the problem is if i add the macro into the Open event of ThisWorkbook and save... heres the wierd part, ill describe then as option 1 and 2:

Option 1

Reopen the file, macro runs perfect and shows me my drop down list without issues... BUT... if i save the document with that data validation in place, when i open the file again it says is corrupted and has to recover the file, so my sheet formating goes to crap and i have to do it all over again.

Option 2
   Reopen the file, macro runs, i get my data validation, THEN i execute a .Clear on the cell and then save the file, if i do it that way when i open the file its not corrupted.

I dont know what to do to have this fixed, it was working fine until i started adding more code to that macro, now its corrupting my file again everytime i save it with the data validation in place :S, heres the code of the macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ocName As String
    Dim neName As String
    Dim arNE(8000) As String
    Dim arOC(8000) As String
    Dim mon As Variant
    Dim mn As Variant
    Dim myList As String
    Dim val As Integer

    Range("O5").Select

    mon = Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE")
    mn = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")

    i = 1
    For m = 0 To 11
        neName = Dir("\\Server-PC\E$\Grupos\Empaque\Hortalizas\Notas de Entrada\" & m + 1 & ".- " & mon(m) & " (N)\")

        Do While neName <> ""
            If Mid(neName, InStr(neName, " ") + 1, InStr(InStr(neName, " ") + 1, neName, "-", vbBinaryCompare) - InStr(neName, " ") - 1) = "OCF" Then
                arNE(i) = Mid(neName, InStr(neName, " ") + 1, InStr(InStr(neName, " ") + 1, neName, " ", vbBinaryCompare) - InStr(neName, " ") - 1)
                i = i + 1
            End If
            neName = Dir()
        Loop
    Next m

    j = 1
    For n = 0 To 11
        ocName = Dir("\\Server-PC\E$\Grupos\Grupo Manga Menor\Ordenes de Compra\2019\ORDENES DE COMPRA\" & mn(n) & ".-" & mon(n) & "\04.-HORTALIZAS\")

        Do While ocName <> ""
            If Left(ocName, InStr(ocName, "-") - 1) = "OCF" Then
                arOC(j) = Left(ocName, InStr(ocName, " ") - 1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
            ocName = Dir()
        Loop
    Next n

    val = 0
    For ocj = j - 1 To 1 Step -1
        For nei = 1 To i - 1
            If arOC(ocj) = arNE(nei) Then
                val = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next nei

        If val = 0 Then myList = myList & arOC(ocj) & ","

        val = 0
    Next ocj

    With Range("O5").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=myList
    End With

    Range("O5").Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: It is likely that your file was already somehow corrupt before you run the code but Excel didn't detect it. Actually the XML file formats (`xlsm` and `xlsx`) are known to cause a lot file corruptions. Try to save your file in the binary `xlsb` format. This will also use less disk space and is much more robust against file corruption (actually I've never seen one).

Comment: What is the exact value of `myList`? Can you step through the code and share it?

Comment: Note that your array `mn(n)` can easily be replaced with `Format$(n + 1, "00")` which uses your loop counter and formats it into a two digit number without an array.

Comment: I would suggest to put a `Stop` in the first row of the code and then run it line by line,  consecutively press F8 and see what happens.

Comment: @FaneDuru How would that help? The file gets corruptet on saving/re-opening only. There is nothing to see while running the code.

Comment: @PeH: You are right... I superficially read only the part saying that his code manually runs but not when in the `Workbook_Open event`. (Only) now I could see the workbook corruption problem...

Comment: @Peh, i saved it as xlsb and now when i open it it still says it was corrupted but when i click on recovery it doesnt screw up my formating but also after repair, i get the following error "Repaired Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.bin part", thing is if i save it and open the saved one i still get the same corrupt and repair error, i guess theres a problem in the sheet1.bin part but it doesnt tell me what it is, ill inspect the code and see what i can find out :-(

Comment: @Pᴇʜ and about the mn(n) i do that because my excel is in english but the folder names are in spanish, so i created a month array to bypass that limitation.... cause i dont wanna set my excel to spanish -.-

Comment: @Javier `mn(n)` is only the numbers array, I was awara of the spanish months. • Well that looks like your workbook is corrupt in general. Excel's repair is not very good. The only way to reall fix is to open up a new Excel file and copy over the data (values and formulas only, no formattings!). Then copy the macros. Save as xlsb and it should be fixed.

Comment: @SiddharthRout the value of myList is a list of the comparisons between arNE and arOC, i add to the list all the items from arOC that doesnt exist in arNE

Comment: @Pᴇʜ im sorry didnt pay enough atention to ur response, ur right lol, ill replace it right away, im still new to vba so i dont know all those pescky little tricks hehe, nice one, thanks for that :-)

Question: doesnt Format(Date, "mm") does the same? i cant test it right now cause its december and the result is 12 hehe

Comment: ok i just test Format(Date, "mm") using Format("1/05/2019", "mm") and the result was 01 so it works lol

Comment: @Javier I recommend not to mess with dates (that are actually strings). In `Format("1/05/2019", "mm")` the `"1/05/2019"` is **not a date**. It is just a **string** (that looks like a date) and you let the computer guess which date this could be. But the computer cannot say 100% sure if it is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` so it is likely that it fails. **Never** convert strings into date implicitly! Always use something like the [DateSerial function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) to create a real date.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ interesting tip, tyvm again for ur help :-) but i still havent found a way to fix my corruption issue :-(

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a completely new Workbook from scratch, just copying in the macros? If yes it is a bug in Excel and you can report it to Microsoft Support. If no, your current workbook is broken and you need to start a clean new one.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i didnt do this in time and now its new year, that means we started from scrach, there are now just a couple of files on the January folder and the corruption is not happening anymore, i guess its like i said b4, if the command is too bulky it will corrupt the file if i set it to run when the document start :-(